# How to synchronise algolia with database only when deleting, adding and updating model instance

Tags: django, algolia

According to the [algoliasearch-django](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django) documentation:

> `AUTO_INDEXING`: automatically synchronize the models with Algolia (default to `True`).

From my understanding, if I set `AUTO_INDEXING` to True, whenever I update a model instance or update model (e.g. add a new field), it will synchronise Algolia with my own database (or model). However, what I want to do is synchronise Algolia *on demand*, for example, only synchronise them when a model instance is changed, added or deleted. Is there any way to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enabling `AUTO_INDEXING`, you tell Algolia's Django integration to connect to Django's [`pre-save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) and [`post-save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save) Signals. These give an opportunity to react when one of your instances is updated, used here by Algolia to sync these changes in your index.

[As you can see in `django/db/models/base.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L744), these are the only signals sent when calling a model's `save()` method:

```
if not meta.auto_created:
    pre_save.send(
        sender=origin, instance=self, raw=raw, using=using,
        update_fields=update_fields,
    )     

#...

# Signal that the save is complete
if not meta.auto_created:
    post_save.send(
        sender=origin, instance=self, created=(not updated),
        update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
    )
```

So Algolia's  `AUTO_INDEXING` can only rely on these ones as a [trigger to update your records](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django/blob/master/algoliasearch_django/registration.py#L65):

```
    if (isinstance(auto_indexing, bool) and
            auto_indexing) or self.__auto_indexing:
        # Connect to the signalling framework.
        post_save.connect(self.__post_save_receiver, model)
        pre_delete.connect(self.__pre_delete_receiver, model)

def __post_save_receiver(self, instance, **kwargs):
    """Signal handler for when a registered model has been saved."""
    logger.debug('RECEIVE post_save FOR %s', instance.__class__)
    self.save_record(instance, **kwargs)

def __pre_delete_receiver(self, instance, **kwargs):
    """Signal handler for when a registered model has been deleted."""
    logger.debug('RECEIVE pre_delete FOR %s', instance.__class__)        
    self.delete_record(instance)
```

---

With this in mind, there is no way for `AUTO_INDEXING` to guess if you called `instance.save()` *because you created a new instance* or *because your model was updated, updating all existing instances*. `AUTO_INDEXING` is designed to trigger indexing **everytime** your instances are updated (be it by adding a new field, changing current fields, adding an instance or deleting one), to ensure your Algolia index is always in sync with your Django database.

If you want to implement a more custom handling of sync with Algolia, you can:

- Disable `AUTO_INDEXING`
- In your `apps.py` after registering your Model with Algolia, connect to the appropriate signals:

  ```
      algoliasearch.register(Contact, ContactIndex)
      post_save.connect(my_post_save_receiver, ContactIndex)
      pre_delete.connect(my_pre_delete_receiver, ContactIndex)
  ```
- And in your `my_post_save_receiver`/`my_pre_save_receiver` methods, process the Signal arguments to decide if you want to call `index.save_record(instance)`.

Have a look at the [Signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/) and the [Signals guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals). Please note the  [duplicate signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals) section.